# NSOpenPanel always tries to rename files on click

Tags: macos, cocoa, foundation, nsopenpanel

I'm using an `NSOpenPanel` to let users select a file like so:

```
  NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc] init];
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = YES;
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = NO;
    openPanel.allowedFileTypes = @[@"mov", @"mp4"];
    openPanel.allowsOtherFileTypes = NO;

    [openPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            [self.editorWindowController loadVideoWithUrl:openPanel.URL];
        }

    }];
```

Everything works great, the only problem is that when you click on a file, the cursor is set to a text editing mode, so it tries to rename the file. Clicking anywhere else otherwise selects the row like normal. Thanks

Comment: I made a new Cocoa app, added an NSButton, and hooked up its action to run exactly this code (except the `editorWindowController` part, because you haven't provided that), and I can't reproduce your issue.  What version of OS X, and Xcode?  Do you have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @Ssswift. Thats really all the code that is executing, from the menu bar File > Open.

Comment: Forgot to mention there are some views that have their own mouse cursors, but not sure why they would interfere with an NSOpenPanel

Comment: Can you rename the file or is it just the I-beam?

Comment: @Willeke You can rename the file. I even removed all code from the project so no windows are loaded, and ran the code above in the  appDelegate didFinish method. It still shows up strangely

Answer (score 2):

The problem was simple but painstaking to find. I had the following piece of code that was affecting all NSTableViews:

```
extension NSTableView {

    override open func validateProposedFirstResponder(_ responder: NSResponder, for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```